# Module is semisimple if and only if all its finitely generated submodules are semisimple

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

> I'm trying to show whether a module is semisimple if and only if all its finitely generated submodules are semisimple is true or not.

I know that a semisimple module has semisimple submodules, but not really sure on the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Definition.** A module is *semisimple* if it is the sum of simple submodules.
>
> **Theorem 1.** *Every submodule of a semisimple module is semisimple.*
>
> **Theorem 2.** *Every module is the sum of its finitely generated submodules.*

Suppose $M$ is semisimple. If $L$ is a finitely generated submodule of $M$, then $L$ is semisimple by theorem 1.

Suppose every finitely generated submodule of $M$ is semisimple. Then $M$ is the sum of simple submodules by theorem 2.

Comment: I feel like this is obvious, but why is a module the sum of its finitely generated submodules?

Comment: @TheProblem The element $x\in M$ belongs to the finitely generated submodule generated by $x$.